# Creating a Randomized Schedule in R for 18 Teams with Specific Conditions

Tags: r, algorithm

I'm looking for assistance in generating a schedule for a sports league using R programming. Here are the conditions:

- Number of Teams: 18
- Schedule Requirements: Each team should have 2 home games and 2 away games, totaling 4 matches. Additionally, teams should ideally play against the same opponent a maximum of 1 time.
- Schedule Generation: The schedule should be generated randomly.

I'd appreciate any guidance or code snippets that could help me achieve this. Thanks in advance for your help!

My previous attempts failed because my conditions were never met.

Comment: reflect on how you would do this by hand, if there are concrete steps you could follow to achieve the goal, this would be an algorithm,. then implement that algorithm in R code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a long winded solution; with a bit more effort, this could be worked over to reduce repetition by the use of functions, but because this is only a 4 round affair, I didnt put the effort in for that.

```
library(tidyverse)

# i'll just go ahead and write code that in principle can work for 26 teams as I'll use letters of alphabet to represent team names
set.seed(42) # for reproducibility
number_of_teams <- 18 
(all_team_names <- letters[1:18])

# we pick teams in rounds, first we pick home teams, then we pick random away teams for them
# we repeat this swapping the home and away members, and additionally we check that before we pair a team
# they did not compete previously, if they did we throw that pair and pick another, check it again etc, 

# round 1 
home_teams_round_1 <- sample(x = all_team_names,
       size=number_of_teams/2,
       replace = FALSE)
away_teams_round_1 <- setdiff(all_team_names,home_teams_round_1)

(round_1 <- map2_df(home_teams_round_1,away_teams_round_1,\(h,a){tibble(
  home=h,away=a,round=1)}))
(round_history <- round_1)
# round 2 gets more interesting because of desire to avoid repeat matches
home_teams_round_2 <- away_teams_round_1
away_teams_round_2 <- home_teams_round_1

round_2 <- list()

for(ht in home_teams_round_2){
   # for each ht lets make a randomly ordered list  of remaining away teams
  # exclude each away team if it was played by the specific ht in the prior rounds
  # and also exclude it if chosen in this round so that it doesnt get reused
  away_teams_round_2 <- sample(away_teams_round_2,size = length(away_teams_round_2), replace=FALSE)
  for (a in away_teams_round_2){
    
    competed_before_rows <- filter(round_history,
           ht == home  | ht == away,
           a == home | a==away)
    if(nrow(competed_before_rows)==0){
      print("got")
      # they didnt compete before so we can pair them and record that,
      # eliminate the away team here from the away teams list for the round
      # and continue with next ht
      round_2 <- append(round_2,list(tibble(
        home=ht,away=a,round=2)))
       away_teams_round_2 <- setdiff(away_teams_round_2,a)
       break;
    } else {
      print("skipped")
      # they competed before so skip action with them
    }
  }
}

round_2 <- list_rbind(round_2)
(round_history <- bind_rows(round_1,round_2))

# round 3 gets more interesting because of desire to avoid repeat matches
home_teams_round_3 <- setdiff(all_team_names,home_teams_round_2)
away_teams_round_3 <- home_teams_round_2

round_3 <- list()

for(ht in home_teams_round_3){
  # for each ht lets make a randomly ordered list  of remaining away teams
  # exclude each away team if it was played by the specific ht in the prior rounds
  # and also exclude it if chosen in this round so that it doesnt get reused
  away_teams_round_3 <- sample(away_teams_round_3,size = length(away_teams_round_3), replace=FALSE)
  for (a in away_teams_round_3){
    
    competed_before_rows <- filter(round_history,
                                   ht == home  | ht == away,
                                   a == home | a==away)
    if(nrow(competed_before_rows)==0){
      print("got")
      # they didnt compete before so we can pair them and record that,
      # eliminate the away team here from the away teams list for the round
      # and continue with next ht
      round_3 <- append(round_3,list(tibble(
        home=ht,away=a,round=3)))
      away_teams_round_3 <- setdiff(away_teams_round_3,a)
      break;
    } else {
      print("skipped")
      # they competed before so skip action with them
    }
  }
}

round_3 <- list_rbind(round_3)
(round_history <- bind_rows(round_history,round_3))

# round 4 gets more interesting because of desire to avoid repeat matches
home_teams_round_4 <- setdiff(all_team_names,home_teams_round_3)
away_teams_round_4 <- home_teams_round_3

round_4 <- list()

for(ht in home_teams_round_4){
  # for each ht lets make a randomly ordered list  of remaining away teams
  # exclude each away team if it was played by the specific ht in the prior rounds
  # and also exclude it if chosen in this round so that it doesnt get reused
  away_teams_round_4 <- sample(away_teams_round_4,size = length(away_teams_round_4), replace=FALSE)
  for (a in away_teams_round_4){
    
    competed_before_rows <- filter(round_history,
                                   ht == home  | ht == away,
                                   a == home | a==away)
    if(nrow(competed_before_rows)==0){
      print("got")
      # they didnt compete before so we can pair them and record that,
      # eliminate the away team here from the away teams list for the round
      # and continue with next ht
      round_4 <- append(round_4,list(tibble(
        home=ht,away=a,round=4)))
      away_teams_round_4 <- setdiff(away_teams_round_4,a)
      break;
    } else {
      print("skipped")
      # they competed before so skip action with them
    }
  }
}

round_4 <- list_rbind(round_4)
(round_history <- bind_rows(round_history,round_4))
```

```
round_history_results <- tibble::tribble(
  ~home, ~away, ~round,
  "q",   "c",      1,
  "e",   "f",      1,
  "a",   "g",      1,
  "i",   "h",      1,
  "j",   "k",      1,
  "d",   "l",      1,
  "b",   "m",      1,
  "n",   "o",      1,
  "p",   "r",      1,
  "c",   "n",      2,
  "f",   "q",      2,
  "g",   "p",      2,
  "h",   "a",      2,
  "k",   "d",      2,
  "l",   "e",      2,
  "m",   "i",      2,
  "o",   "j",      2,
  "r",   "b",      2,
  "a",   "f",      3,
  "b",   "c",      3,
  "d",   "g",      3,
  "e",   "m",      3,
  "i",   "l",      3,
  "j",   "r",      3,
  "n",   "h",      3,
  "p",   "k",      3,
  "q",   "o",      3,
  "c",   "p",      4,
  "f",   "d",      4,
  "g",   "j",      4,
  "h",   "q",      4,
  "k",   "n",      4,
  "l",   "b",      4,
  "m",   "a",      4,
  "o",   "i",      4,
  "r",   "e",      4
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have too many teams, you can try a randomization method like Monte Carlo, for example

```
game_scheduler <- function(nTeams, k = 2) {
  v <- seq_len(nTeams)
  x <- rep(v, each = k)
  df <- data.frame(Home = x, Away = c(tail(x, -(k + 1)), head(x, k + 1)))
  out <- c()
  repeat {
    if (nrow(df) == 0) {
      break
    }
    repeat {
      k <- sample.int(nrow(df), length(v) / 2)
      if (!length(setdiff(v, unlist(df[k, ])))) {
        out <- c(out, list(df[sort(k), ]))
        df <- df[-k, ]
        break
      }
    }
  }
  setNames(out, paste0("round", seq_along(out)))
}
```

and after a while of simulation, you will obtain

```
> game_scheduler(18)
$round1
   Home Away
2     1    3
4     2    4
10    5    7
12    6    8
18    9   11
20   10   12
25   13   14
29   15   16
33   17   18

$round2
   Home Away
6     3    5
8     4    6
13    7    8
17    9   10
21   11   12
26   13   15
28   14   16
34   17    1
36   18    2

$round3
   Home Away
3     2    3
7     4    5
11    6    7
15    8    9
19   10   11
23   12   13
27   14   15
31   16   17
35   18    1

$round4
   Home Away
1     1    2
5     3    4
9     5    6
14    7    9
16    8   10
22   11   13
24   12   14
30   15   17
32   16   18
```